# ZF: Disable Resource Plugin in application.ini

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-cache, zend-application, zend-config

How can I disable cache in the cli enviroment?

Reason being, the system user that executes the script is not allowed to write to the cache directory, thus the script is unable to execute.

In my application.ini I have

```
[production]

resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.name = Core
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.customFrontendNaming = false
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.options.lifetime = 7200
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = true
resources.cachemanager.database.backend.name = File
resources.cachemanager.database.backend.customBackendNaming = false
resources.cachemanager.database.backend.options.cache_dir = HTTPDOCS_PATH "/data/cache/database"
resources.cachemanager.database.frontendBackendAutoload = false

[cli : production]
```

*<]:-)

Comment: I'm asking how to disable cache in CLI, which inherits production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.options.caching = false
```

See the [API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Cache/Zend_Cache_Core.html) and the [ZF Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.frontends.html) for the `$_options` property in `Zend_Cache_Core`

Comment: resources.cachemanager.database.frontend.options.caching = false resources.cachemanager.database.backend.options.cache_dir = "/tmp"
Solved my problem - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I see no obvious way to disable a plugin in a config section that was registered in a parent section. It would be cool if `Zend_Config_Ini` allowed multiple inheritance, kind of like how an HTML element can multiple CSS classes in the class attribute. (Does it? I'm guessing not). Then you could put the plugin registration into one section `[myplugsection]`, allow `[production]` to extend `[myplug]` while `[cli]` does not, kind of like how Doctrine has `actAs` templates and beahviors.

The next best thing might be to create a section called something like [core]containing most of what you now habe in `[production]`. Both `[production]` and `[cli]` could extend `[core]`, but `[production]` would register the plugin while `[cli]` would not.

Of course, an alternative would be to could move the plugin registration into Bootstrap where you have finer control of the plugin registration. In particular, you can call `$front->unregisterPlugin()`, where `$front` is the `FrontController`.

Just thinking out loud...

Cheers!

Comment: D'oh! Just realized you are talking about resources not plugins. In principle, though, the inheritance scheme I outlined - using `[core]` as commom parent section to `[cli]` and `[production]` should work for any content you put in a section, including `resources.*`.