# How can I unregister plugin in application.ini?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a line in my  application.ini file (in production section):

resources.frontController.plugins.xxx = "Myname_Controller_Plugin_Xxx"

And I want this plugin only in production mode, so my question is: How can I unregister this plugin in development section?

Comment: Can you remove this answer your write an answer and mark it as answered please.

Answer (score 0):

quoting the OP:

> omg, I just found a solution here ->
>   ZF: [Disable Resource Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678334/zf-disable-resource-plugin-in-application-ini) in
>   application.ini